# QUnit ignore error from source

Tags: javascript, jquery, qunit, bacon.js

I wrote some tests using jQuery's qUni for some Bacon.js functions i did.
   However Bacon.js throws an error and qUnit marks the test as failed but the outcome is correct and the equals() methods work ok.

My question is can i make qUnit ignore a type of error or an error from a source ? 
   The error is something like this :
"Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function
Source: ..../static/js/libs/Bacon.js:62"

Thanks

Comment: Not really. qUnit is JavaScript running in the same environment as the crashing code. It _is_ application code actually.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without seeing your actual tests it's hard to say exactly how you need to structure the tests, but if the `Error` being thrown is *expected* behavior, then you can use [QUnit's `throws()` assertion](http://api.qunitjs.com/throws/) to make sure that happens as expected:

```
QUnit.test("this should throw an error...", function(assert) {
    assert.throws(
        function() {
            someFunctionThatThrowsAnError("maybe with a 'bad' arg versus good?");
        },
        /undefined is not a function/, // regex to match, any other Error fails the test
        "Error should be thrown with invalid arguments"
    );
});
```